# "Assertion failed: you need to wait for the runtime to be ready" Error when calling a C function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

I am trying out a simple example to call a C function compiled to .wasm with JavaScript.

This is the `counter.c` file:

```
#include <emscripten.h>

int counter = 100;

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int count() {  
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
}
```

I compiled it using `emcc counter.c -s WASM=1 -o counter.js`.

My `main.js` JavaScript file:

```
const count = Module.cwrap('count ', 'number');
console.log(count());
```

My `index.html` file only loads both .js files in the body, nothing else:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="counter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

The error I am getting is:

`Uncaught abort("Assertion failed: you need to wait for the runtime to be ready (e.g. wait for main() to be called)") at Error`

when I try to call `count()` in `main.js`. **How can I wait for the runtime to be ready?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a quick solution. I needed to modify `main.js` to:

```
Module['onRuntimeInitialized'] = onRuntimeInitialized;
const count = Module.cwrap('count ', 'number');

function onRuntimeInitialized() {
    console.log(count());
}
```

This alters the `Module` object that is defined in the `counter.js` script generated by emscripten.

Comment: onRuntimeInitialized() never seems to get executed.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer works, as specified [here](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#how-can-i-tell-when-the-page-is-fully-loaded-and-it-is-safe-to-call-compiled-functions) under the "**How can I tell when the page is fully loaded and it is safe to call compiled functions?**" header, where the article also mentions another way to wait to call code where you include a main function in your C/C++ code that calls a javascript function through the C/C++ to Javascript API like so:

```
#include <emscripten.h>
int main() {
    EM_ASM(const count = Module.cwrap('count ', 'number'); console.log(count()););
    return 0;
}
```

This works because the main function always executes when the runtime is initialized.

Comment: It should be `EM_ASM`, not `ES_ASM`.